# jquery lazyload 2 column image only work on left side

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload, lazy-loading

I have a page that show 2 column of image side by side in a tablet view and above, I use lazyload jquery, the problem is when i scroll through, it only lazyload the left column image and the right side column show the all image after I scroll through all the section image.

Here's the code look like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- image section left side -->
    <img class="lazy" data-original="img1.jpg"> <!-- show up when screen stop here -->
    <img class="lazy" data-original="img2.jpg"> <!-- show up when screen stop here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- image section right side -->
    <img class="lazy" data-original="img3.jpg"> <!-- not shown when screen stop here (also screen stop on img1.jpg) -->
    <img class="lazy" data-original="img4.jpg"> <!-- shown because the end of image section, and also showing img3.jpg all at once -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I used width and height but still not working

Comment: <div class="row> need to be like <div class="row"> same goes for <div class="col-sm-6">

Comment: sorry dude, but that is not what i asking

Answer (score 1):

Set failure_limit parameter to 9999. It is working.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn", failure_limit: 9999});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin doesn't work, try [Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/)! ;)
I don't see any problems with multiple columns ...

```js
$(".lazy").lazy();
```

```css
.row {
  width: 200px;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.4/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="lazy" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=1">
    <img class="lazy" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="lazy" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=3">
    <img class="lazy" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i will try it mate, thanks
but maybe i will stick to lazyload first